# Is there a multiValue field sort workaround in solr

Tags: solr

I am trying to look for alternative ways to sort a multivalue field.

I know that this question has been asked before and the solutions talk about min and max but that is not the strategy i am looking for.

Is there a way we can do a COPY of the multivalue over to another field which can be used for sorting?

For example like this:

```
<field name="cat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" 
multiValued="true"/>

<copyField source="cat" dest="firstcat"/>

<field name="firstcat" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" 
multiValued="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question.

The copyfield above will not work and will throw an exception when there is more than one value in the multivalue string.  I mean, duh. Obviously.

One working solution is to use the updateRequestProcessorChain configuration in the solrconfig.xml and add it to the update handler chain.

Here is a sample:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="concatFields">
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">str1</str>
    <str name="dest">str2</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.ConcatFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="fieldName">str2</str>
    <str name="delimiter">_</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.CloneFieldUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="source">str2</str>
    <str name="dest">str3</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />    
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

And then chain the processor to the path:

```
<initParams path="/update/**">
<lst name="defaults">
<str name="update.chain">concatFields</str>
</lst>
</initParams>
```